# DFS - comparing the time and score complexity of two connected graph

Tags: search, graph, time-complexity, depth-first-search, space-complexity

Imagine the following graph (it is not a real graph), which upper level presents an acyclic directed graph with `n` nodes, while the lower level presents an acyclic directed graph with `m` nodes. Each node in the upper level is connected to a few nodes in the lower level (let's say each node in the upper level covers a few nodes in the lower level). So, `n` is less than `m` (each node in upper level at least covers 2 nodes in lower level).

[image]

My questions are:

1- What are the time and space complexities using the `depth-first search` algorithm to find all sequences from a certain node in the upper level and in the lower level? and how these time and space complexity of two levels can be compared (how they are related)?

My answer about time and space complexity, which I am suspicious about, are as follow:

- Upper level: time complexity:o(n), space complexity: o(n+e) (e:
  number of edges).
- Lower level:time complexity:o(m),space complexity:o(m+e) (e: number of edges).

But I can not find the relations between these two.

2- If we want to find all possible sequences from a single node in the lower level of the graph, if an additional node will be added to this graph, how the number of sequences increase (for the worst case scenario)?

Any idea is appreciated!

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you are asking for. Are you asking for the time/space complexity of performing a full DFS traversal starting from a vertex in the upper layer vs. starting from a vertex in the lower layer? When starting in the upper layer, the graph size is obtained by adding the number of vertices and edges in the upper and lower layer. The time/space complexity is then the [standard DFS complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) for a graph of that size (i.e. time complexity O(n+m+e_upper + e_lower) and space complexity O(n+m)).

Comment: When starting in the lower layer, the upper layer can never be reached, so the reachable graph size is m vertices and e_lower edges. The complexity of the DFS traversal is then the standard DFS complexity for a graph of that size (i.e. time complexity O(m+e_lower) and space complexity O(m). Regarding question 2), it is not clear to me what you mean by "all possible sequences" and what the precise meaning of "adding a node" is (i.e. will the node be isolated, or will it be attached to the existing graph by edges? If so, how many edges etc.).